# jquery version Issue

Tags: jquery, version

I was working with jquery v1.3.2 and following piece of code was all working nice

$(".textid").live('click',function(){
  textbox_input=true;
 });

But as soon as I updated to jquery v1.4.2 above piece of code just not working as expected!!.

Just to test script identified the click event correctly I added following

```
$(".textid").click(function(){
    alert('you clicked me');
});
```

and message pop up saying "Load Jquery First"  {this come sometime}

I checked my include list and jquery is the first include.....

Can someone guide me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Priti

Comment: Does "not working as expected" mean not working at all? What does your javascript debugger (e.g. Firebug) say is happening?

Answer (score 1):

either some other code fails
or
your link to 1.4.2 is broken.